# Parse a JSON object using GET method "Volley"

Tags: android, get, android-volley

I'm stuck when I try get my articles when move from POST method to GET method from my api.. I try to change "Request.Method.GET" but still not working..I also try the GET method for volley from other post but i dont know how to get all my "category_id" ....Below is my codes:

```
public void getPosts(){

        if(refreshed || articleList.size() == 0) {
            swipeContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        String apiLink;

//        if(nextUrl != null)
//            apiLink = nextUrl;
//        else
            apiLink = api.getArticlesByCategoryAPI();

        pulling = true;

        final HashMap<String, String> postParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        postParams.put("secret_key", api.getSecretKey());
        postParams.put("id", String.valueOf(categoryId));

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, apiLink, new JSONObject(postParams),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        Log.d("object", "test here");

                        try {
                            JSONObject resultObj = response.getJSONObject("articles");
                            JSONObject categoryObj = response.getJSONObject("article_category");
                            JSONArray articlesObj = resultObj.getJSONArray("data");

                            if (articlesObj.length() > 0) {

                                totalArticle = resultObj.getInt("total");
                                Log.d("totalarticle", String.valueOf(totalArticle));

                                articleList.clear();

                                for (int x = 0; x < articlesObj.length(); x++) {

                                    if(x == 19){
                                        break;
                                    }

                                    JSONObject articleObj = articlesObj.getJSONObject(x);

                                    Article article = new Article();

                                    Category category = new Category();

                                    article.setId(articleObj.getInt("id"));
                                    article.setTitle(articleObj.getString("title"));
                                    article.setStandFirst(articleObj.getString("standfirst"));
                                    article.setContent(articleObj.getString("content_html"));
                                    article.setThumbnail(articleObj.getString("banner_url_thumb"));
//                                    article.setViewCount(articleObj.getInt("view_count"));
                                    article.setDatePublished(articleObj.getString("date_publish_web"));
                                    article.setUrl(articleObj.getString("url"));
                                    articleList.add(article);

                                    Log.d("listsize", String.valueOf(articleList.size()));

                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    category.setId(categoryObj.getInt("id"));
                                    category.setName(categoryObj.getString("name"));
                                    category.setStatus(categoryObj.getString("status"));
                                    article.setCategory(category);


                                }

                                swipeContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                if (refreshed) {
                                    swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                                    refreshed = false;
                                }

                                totalItemCount = 0;
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                pulling = false;

//                                if(resultObj.has("next_page_url") && !resultObj.getString("next_page_url").equals("null")) {
//                                    nextUrl = resultObj.getString("next_page_url");
//                                } else {
//                                    nextUrl = null;
//                                }

                                addScroll();

                            } else {
                                // something to do if zero result
                                System.out.println("ZERO RESULT");
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            System.out.println("FAILED PARSE RESULT: " + e.getMessage());
                            Log.d("cantparse" , e.getMessage());
                        }

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Slow network connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        System.out.println(error.toString());
                        loader.hide();
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Accept", "application/json");
//                params.put("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);

                return params;
            }

        };

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

And below is my api from PAW

[image: API screenshot]

Comment: Go through this tutorial for JSON parsing using volley.https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best Volley example **(I prefer always)** that gives you a better control with GET and POST method using volley.

[Volley With Get/Post Method](http://androiderstack.com/index.php/2018/02/04/how-to-call-api-using-volley-with-get-and-post-method/)

There is a **controller class** that will help you to manage your **GET/POST** request, You can call your web service (API) with two lines of code.

If you find something that confuse you, then you can ask to me anything in this example.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is that when you send a GET request, you need to include the parameters in the actual URL:

> "http://www.yayayayyay.com/params.php?param1=blah&param2=derp3"

Whereas with a POST request, the parameters are sent in a different way which is why you have this in your code:

> final HashMap postParams = new HashMap();

You don't need that code if you're using GET.

[Here](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/android-volley-with-get-and-post-parameters-example/) is some good info.

Also, in my opinion, if you control the server, and POST is working, then there's nothing wrong with that unless you have a reason not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I change my code to this

```
public void getPosts(){

        if(refreshed || articleList.size() == 0) {
            swipeContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        String apiLink;

        if(nextUrl != null)
            apiLink = nextUrl;
        else
            apiLink = api.getArticlesByCategoryAPI()+categoryId;

            Log.d("apilink", apiLink);

        pulling = true;

//        final HashMap<String, String> postParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
//        postParams.put("secret_key", api.getSecretKey());
//        postParams.put("id", String.valueOf(categoryId));

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, apiLink, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
```